# What's the definition of proper subspace of a vector space used in Rudin's Functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, definition, topological-vector-spaces

I'm reading through the Rudin's functional analysis, and theorem 3.5 use the term "Proper Subspace", there's a theorem in chapter 2 that uses the same terminology.

I'm reading through chapter 1 again, and through the glossary as well but I cannot find the definition used.

I guess there must be a standard definition then,

What is such definition?

Comment: It a subspace different  from the vector  space.

Comment: So literally it's a proper subset that is also a vector space, correct?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 2):

$V$ is a proper subspace of $X$ if
$V$ is a subspace of $X$ and $V\subsetneq X$.

I would guess that there is no definition of proper subspace in the book,
since a proper subspace is a subspace that is also a proper subset.

Comment: Does this definition imply that the only proper subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ is $\left\{ 0 \right\}$ and that proper subspaces of topological vector spaces have empty interiors?

Comment: @user8469759 yes